# Find the equilibria of the following system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Find the equilibria of the following system of ODEs
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \dot{x} = ax - y + kx(x^2 + y^2)\\
>   \dot{y} = x - ay + ky(x^2 + y^2)
>   \end{align*}
>
> where $a$ and $k$ are constants, $a > 1$ and $a^2 \geq 1$.

I want to find the equilibria of this system and say something about the behaviour in the phase-plane. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the equilibria.

**What I've tried:** I subtracted the second equation from the first one to arrive at
\begin{align}
ax + ay -y -x+kx(x^2 + y^2) - ky(x^2 + y^2) = 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow a(x + y) - (x+y) + (x - y)k(x^2 + y^2) = 0\\
\Leftrightarrow a - 1 + \dfrac{x - y}{x+y}(x^2 + y^2)k = 0
\end{align}
From here I want to find an expression for $x$ or $y$ but I don't know how to do so.

**Question:** How should I approach this? If I'd get a hint on how to proceed I think I can solve the problem myself.

Thanks!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes!

Comment: Are you sure about the sign structure of the linear terms? To get a limit cycle I would expect the first term to have a minus sign, $\dot x=-ax-y+...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\dot x=\dot y=0$. Multiply the first equation with $x$, the second with $y$ and add to get
$$
0=a(x^2-y^2)+k(x^2+y^2)^2.
$$
Now do everything askew, multiply the first equation with $y$, the second with $x$ and subtract to get
$$
0=2axy-(x^2+y^2)
$$
Apart from the origin, there are also solutions for $y=q_\pm x=(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1})x$, and from the first equation,
$$
y^2-x^2=4kax^2y^2\implies q^2-1=4kaq^2x^2,~~ x^2=\frac{q^2-1}{4kaq^2}
$$
which only gives real solutions for $q=q_+=a+\sqrt{a^2-1}>1$.

---

Example with $a=2$, $k=3$ using WolframAlpha

```
streamplot[{2x-y+3x(x^2+y^2), x-2y+3y(x^2+y^2)}, {x,-1.5,1.5}, {y,-1.5,1.5}]
```

[image]

showing a saddle point at the origin and two additional centers at the other two stationary points. At the boundary of the plot all solutions point outwards.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for the equilibrium poins we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 a x-y +k x\left(x^2+y^2\right)=0 \\
 x-a y+k y\left(x^2+y^2\right)=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

giving the equilibrium points. (with the help of Wolfram)

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{a \left(a^2-1\right) k+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}}}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\left(\sqrt{a^4
   \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}-a^3 k\right) \sqrt{-\frac{a \left(a^2-1\right) k+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}}}{\sqrt{2} a^2 k}
   \\
 \frac{\sqrt{-\frac{a \left(a^2-1\right) k+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}}}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\left(a^3 k-\sqrt{a^4
   \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}\right) \sqrt{-\frac{a \left(a^2-1\right) k+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}}}{\sqrt{2} a^2 k} \\
 -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{-k a^3+k a+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}}}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{-k a^3+k a+\sqrt{a^4
   \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}} \left(k a^3+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2} a^2 k} \\
 \frac{\sqrt{\frac{-k a^3+k a+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}}}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\sqrt{\frac{-k a^3+k a+\sqrt{a^4
   \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k^2}} \left(k a^3+\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2} a^2 k} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

for instance, with $a = 2, k = 3$ we have

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
 0 & 0 \\
 -0.19666 & -0.733945 \\
 0.19666 & 0.733945 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

the Jacobian being

$$
J = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a+k \left(3 x^2+y^2\right) & 2 k x y-1 \\
 k \left(3 x^2+y^2\right)+1 & 2 k x y-a \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and at each equilibrium point

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & -1 \\
 1 & -a \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a k+2 \sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k} & \frac{\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^3 k}-1 \\
 -a+1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2 \sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{k a^2} & \frac{\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^3 k}-a \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a k+2 \sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^2 k} & \frac{\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^3 k}-1 \\
 -a+1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2 \sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{k a^2} & \frac{\sqrt{a^4 \left(a^2-1\right) k^2}}{a^3 k}-a \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
$$

or assuming $a = 2, k = 3$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2. & -1 \\
 1 & -2. \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3.9641 & -0.133975 \\
 1.86603 & 2.9641 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3.9641 & -0.133975 \\
 1.86603 & 2.9641 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
$$

with eigenvalues

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccl}
 -1.73205 & 1.73205 & \text{saddle}\\
 3.4641 & 3.4641 & \text{source}\\
 3.4641 & 3.4641 & \text{source}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Resuming for $a = 2, k = 3$ we have a saddle and two sources.

[image]

Comment: @LutzL Tanks for your corrections. I had manipulated some incorrect formulas.